# How to Hide iPad bar on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I need to help on how to hide iPad address bar or the whole bar at the top when the page is loaded.

I am developing Customer Management system online based system and need to hide iPad address bar because it takes a lot of space when viewing website.

Regards
Eddy

Already tried the following code and nothing.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: When you say IPAD`s address bar, do you mean by Browser`s address bar within IPAD, mostly safari`s ?

Comment: Yes I need to hide address bar on iPad and browser is safar

Answer (score 2):

iPad's Safari's address bar can *only* be hidden if you make your webpage a "webapp" by adding:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

and adding it to the home screen:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/djc8D/show

Comment: @EddyBlackpool - Then unfortunately there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This Would tell the Safari browser to run in fullscreen mode

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Happy coding :)